# Controlling the border-radius after the height of the container has increased

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Round borders can be real purdy sometimes, except when the div increases size. IN this particular situation I have, the div's content is dynamic. It can be one line of text, it can be two, and it can be a paragraph. Problem is, the UI is built with round borders and they look nice with one line of text `~ 34px height` but anything higher than that and the round borders are HUGE!!!.

**Acceptable Option 1** - I would like to know if the round borders ratio can decrease as the height of the element increases. There should a stopping point in this situation so it doesn't go all the way to `0px`

**Acceptable Option 2** - If option 1 is impossible to do, can I detect when the height of an element has gone over the initiated height (i.e. `var h = 34px;`) and by `.addClass()` method or `.css()` method reattach a border-radius with less curvature? **UPDATE** - After further consideration, this would probably be the best solution. Would you agree? ;)

I built a handy-dandy [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/NNroRr) for ya!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course you know that the case with one line of text will look exactly the same if border radius is 17px ?

Comment: Agreed, but I need the one line box to have 34px so that it is consistent with the rest of them. Many other elements around it have 34px border radius. The few that grow to more than one line look more cohesive with the rest of the UI if they had a smaller curvature

Answer (score 0):

In response to option .2 I've provided a solution:

```
var breakpoint = 34;
var divHeight = $("your-div").height()

$("your-div").resize(function(){

    if(divHeight > breakpoint ){
     $("your-div").addClass("<CLASS HERE>")
}else{
     $("your-div").removeClass("<CLASS HERE>")
}
    })
```

This should help some.

Comment: I added it to the Codepen I provided. Didn't work for me. Could you provide a working example demo?